# Manually convert AngularJS $http params object to URL parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Angular's `$http`  service can automatically convert an object into URL params. I.e. in following code params will be converted to `date=2014-12-11T18:00:00.000Z&name=MyName`

```
$http({
     method: "GET",
     url: url,
     params: {date: new Date(), name: 'MyName'}
})
```

**Question:** how I can manually convert my object into url parameters?

I found that I can do it using the `$param` method of JQuery, but the problem is that when using JQuery it converts dates in worng format: `date=Fri+Dec+12+2014+00%3A00%3A00+GMT%2B0600+(Ekaterinburg+Standard+Time)`, but I want to send dates in Angular's format:

`date=2014-12-11T18:00:00.000Z`

In other words I need something like this:

```
var params = {date: new Date(), name: 'MyName'};
var paramsString = angular.toUrlParams(params); // should output `date=2014-12-11T18:00:00.000Z&name=MyName`
```

Comment: Manually or automatically?

Comment: @im1dermike Manually. How I can manually duplicate functionality of `$http` service? I.e. I want manually convert my JSON into URL params in `$http` service way

Comment: Show the code you've tried so far.

Comment: @im1dermike I tried only `$param` function of JQuery, it works, but dates converted in wrong format. Look at updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Convert the dates into that string format before passing them to jQuery.

[It doesn't do anything specific to the dates under-the-hood](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/10399ddcf8a239acc27bdec9231b996b178224d3/src/serialize.js#L50), this is simply the [default way to cast a date object into a string as per the JS spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString).